# Remove decimal using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert my decimal SQL query result in percent. Example I have a 0.295333 I want it to be 30% and if I have a 0.090036 I want it to be 9%.

This is what I have so far.

```
(100 * (sample1/ sample2) ) as 'Percent'
```

I also tried this one but the problem is result comes with **".00"** and I don't know how to remove the decimal.

```
cast (ROUND(100 * (sample1 / sample2),0) As int ) as 'Percent'
```

Comment: you don't need brackets for the sample1 / sample2, really. it should just be `100.0 * sample1 / sample2`

Comment: I would use `100.0 * sample1 / sample2` to avoid unexpected implicit conversion to `int` and truncation of data

Comment: @cha You are right in case if both variables are `INT`

Comment: What does `sample1/ sample2` yield? What datatypes are these columns?

Comment: @x'tian Your second statement looks fine. Give sample variables and what do you expect from them.

Comment: How can you possibly get `.00` if you are casting to an `int`? Where do you see this `.00`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below script..

```
cast (100 * Round((sample1 / sample2),2) As int ) as 'Percent'
```

Answer (score 1):

So as some of the comments pointed out you may need to pay attention to your datatype if one or both of the original columns that you get your decimal from are integer.

One easy way of dealing with that is something like this:

`ColA * ColB * 1.0` which will make sure that your integers are treated as decimals

So if you have SQL Server 2012+ you can use Format and not mess with rounding at all.  Like this `FORMAT(YourDecimal,'#%')`, yep that simple.

```
;WITH cteValues AS (
    SELECT  0.295333 as OriginalValue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0.090036 as OriginalValue
)

SELECT
    OriginalValue
    ,FORMAT(OriginalValue,'#%') as PercentFormat
FROm
    cteValues
```

If you are pre 2012 and do not have format an easy way is to round to the 100th then times by 100 and cast as int `CAST(ROUND(YourDecimal,2) * 100 AS INT)`

```
;WITH cteValues AS (
    SELECT  0.295333 as OriginalValue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0.090036 as OriginalValue
)

SELECT
    OriginalValue
    ,CAST(ROUND(OriginalValue,2) * 100 AS INT) as PercentInt
FROm
    cteValues
```

Because an INT cannot by definition have decimal places, if you are receiving .00 with the method similar to this or the one you have tried, I would ask the following.

- Are you combining (multiplying etc.) the value after casting with another column or value that may be decimal, numeric, or float?
- Are you looking at the query results in a program outside of SSMS that could be formatting the results automatically, e.g. Excel, Access?

Answer (score 1):

- Address your assumptions first.

How does `ROUND` work? Does it guarantee return values and if so, how? What is the precedence of the two columns? Does `Arithmetic operators` influence the results and how?

I only know what I do not know, and any doubt is worth an investigation.

- **THE DIVIDEND OPERATOR**

Since `ROUND` always returns the higher precedence, this is not the problem. It is in fact the divide operator ( `/` ) that may be transforming your values to an integer.

Always verify the variables are consistently of one datatype or `CAST` if either unsure or unable to guarantee (such as insufficiently formatted. I.e. `DECIMAL(4,2)` instead of required `DECIMAL(5,3)` ).

```
DECLARE @Sample1 INT
                , @Sample2 DECIMAL(4,2);
SET @Sample1 = 50;
SET @Sample2 =83.11;

SELECT ROUND( 100 * @Sample1 / @Sample2 , 0 )
```

Returns properly 60.

```
SELECT ROUND( 100 * @Sample2 / @Sample1 , 0)
```

Incorrectly turns variables into integers before rounding.

- The reason is that [DIVIDE - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx) in SQL may return the higher precedence, but any dividend that is an integer returns another integer.

**UPDATE**
This also explains why the decimal remains after ROUND...it is of higher precedence. You can add another cast to transform the non-INT datatype to the preferred format.

```
SELECT CAST( ROUND( <expression>, <Length>) AS INT)
```

Note that in answering your question I learned something myself! :)

Hope this helps.